# Split windows of integrated terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't figure out how to split the integrated windows terminal in VSCode on Windows 7? I see the option of using `⌘\` keys for MacOS in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), but there is no mention of how to accomplish this on Windows. As per the documentation, this can also be achieved by the context-menu by right clicking (where)? But the only option I see in the contextual menu is 'Hide'.

Also, is it possible to have tabs for each terminal window? A [request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10546) was raised for the same, but it was not implemented I believe. Selecting the terminal window from the dropdown is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> on Windows.  There is also a split icon in the terminal - just to the right of the + sign icon (if you are on a recent version of vscode).

You will not get a right-click context menu unless the following is set to `default`:

```
 "terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default",
```

The default setting for that is "`copyPaste`".

And no, terminal tabs hasn't arrived as of v.1.21.1